# Kind of linear property on a function $f: X \to Y$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

A function $f: X \to Y$ is called **linear** iff

$f(x_1+x_2) = f(x_1) + f(x_2)$

It is what I learned.

Is there any concept like 'linear' defined on the functions whose input and output are sets.

A function $f: X \to Y$ is called '**ABCD**' iff
   $f(X1 \cup X2) = f(X1) \cup f(X2)$

Is there any concept corresponding to '**ABCD**' here?

// Thanks, lulu
I clarify here:

f is defined on some fixed set and that X_i denotes subsets of that set.

Comment: May be "additive"?

Comment: Well, if we take the lattice of sets with intersection and union, the property becomes ***join-semilattice homomorphism***.

Comment: This isn't clear.  What are $X,Y$?  I guess they are collections of sets closed under union?  Are they power sets of fixed sets?

Comment: Well, the point should be clarified.  In the posted solution below, the writer is assuming that you have $f$ is defined on some fixed set and that $X_i$ denotes subsets of that set.  If that's what you intended then indeed all  functions satisfy your rule.   If, to the contrary, you meant $X$ is some collection of sets (closed under union) and $f$ is defined on that collection, then not all functions satisfy your rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. If $f(x_1+x_2)=f(x_1)+f(x_2)$ then $f$ is called additive and not linear !

If $X$ and $Y$ are vector spaces over a field $F$ and we have additional

$f( \alpha x)= \alpha f(x)$ for all $ \alpha \in F$ and all $x \in X$,

then f is called linear.

2. For each function $f:X \to Y$ we have

$f(X_1 \cup X_2)=f(X_1) \cup f(X_2)$ for all subsets $X_1,X_2$ of $X$

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.
So the second statement is always true for all kinds of such functions? Doesn't this theorem have any name? (since it's too trivial?...)

Comment: 2. seems false to me. Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are sets of nonempty, finite subsets of $\mathbb R$, and $f(X)$ is a singleton containing $max(X)$ – then $f(A\cup B)=\{max(max(A), max(B))\}$ while $f(A)\cup f(B)=\{max(A), max(B)\}$ which are not the same. What's more, how about $f$ which value is *not* a set? The RHS $f(A)\cup f(B)$ might not even be defined...

Comment: What you have written seems very confused to me !

Comment: The confusion lies in the OP's intent.  If $f$ is just defined on some collection of sets, then the desired property need not hold.  For example, say $X$ is the power set on $\{1,2\}$ and for $S\in X$  define $f(S)=\emptyset$ if $S\neq \emptyset$ and $f(\emptyset)=\{1\}$.